# Restful webservices help in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Below is my code which is giving a null pointer exception on execution. Please help me resolve this issue:

```
@POST
@GET
@Path("/Auth/{uname}")
public String checkUserAccess(@PathParam("uname") String username) {
    String message = svc.checkUserAccess(username);
    return message;
}
```

**Service Interface:**

```
public String checkUserAccess(String id);
```

**Service Implementation:**

```
public String checkUserAccess(String id) {
    String message = Dao.checkUserAccess(id);
    return message;
}
```

**DAO Interface:**

```
public String checkUserAccess(String id);
```

**DAO Implementation:**

```
public String checkUserAccess(String id) {
    String result = null;
    String user = propertyProvider.getProperty("Auth");
    if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(id))
        result = "Valid User";
    else
        result = "Invalid User";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code should be part of the question, not a comment.

Comment: Just debug the code. It shouldn't be a problem to figure it out. BTW it not good practice to annotated the same method with '@POST' and '@GET'. Maybe some JAX-RS implementations will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the line of code where you are getting user from property provider is causing the `NullPointerException`. i.e.

```
String user = propertyProvider.getProperty("Auth");
```

I guess you are getting user as `null`. So `if( user.equalsIgnoreCase(id) )` is throwing `NullPointerException`. Put a null check before authenticating the user.

```
if(user!=null && user.equalsIgnoreCase(id) ) {
    result = "Valid User"; 
else 
    result = "Invalid User"; 
return result; }
```

Comment: No Luck Still getting the NullPointer Exception

Comment: Could you please post stack-trace? Edit your question and post it.

Comment: And where are you getting propertyProvider from? Check if that's null.

Comment: 23:20:58,482 INFO  [Service] Input parameter is=============>523
23:20:58,482 ERROR [[springmvc]] Servlet.service() for servlet springmvc threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.portal.restservice.Service.checkUserAccess(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

Comment: Getting Value from the Property Provider and it wasnt null

Comment: The exception is thrown from Service Class' checkUserAccess method. Check if jbomDao is null. Because that's the only object ref you are using to invoke methods from service method.

Comment: Sorry Jeevan I didnt get you what you really said

Comment: I said you are calling DAO method from service class using Dao.checkUserAccess(id). Check if this Dao object is null or not.

Comment: Kept a logger before the below line but it didnt reach even there
String message = Dao.checkUserAccess(id);

Comment: That means your service method itself is not getting called. Check entire flow from controller to dao if anything is null. First check if service class object is null or not in controller when you call svc.checkUserAccess(username);.

Comment: svc.checkUserAccess(username);
Kept a Loggger Before this line only it showed but when the above line was called it was throwing a Null Pointer Exception but not sure why and checked the parameter that was being passed to that checkuseracces method even I was getting that but still null pointer exception

Comment: Found the solution minute changes in my application Context .xml file thanks Jeevan for your valuable time